# Write $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^{n-1} = 1+x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4+8x^5+13x^6+21x^7+34x^8+55x^9+89x^{10}+... $ as a power series

Tags: power-series

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^{n-1} = 1+x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4+8x^5+13x^6+21x^7+34x^8+55x^9+89x^{10}+\ldots $
Use the ratio test to prove that f(x) converges if |x|< $\frac{1}{2}$
. 
Edit: $a_n$ in this case is a Fibonacci sequence

Comment: You have to find out how to express $a_n$ in terms of $n$. That isn't at all clear in this case. Besides the fact that *any* sequence of real numbers could follow the given coefficients.

Comment: Hint: $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1}$.

Comment: You need a closed form expression for the $n$-th term of the Fibonacci sequence it seems.

Comment: The limit of the ratios will be $|x| \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. So you will eed to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<2$ (it is actually $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, as it turns out).

Answer (score 3):

Use [Fibonacci closed form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression):
$$ a_n = \frac{\varphi^n - (-\varphi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}
$$
You can also use the fact that $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1}$, so let
$$ r = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n + a_{n-1}}{a_n} = 1 + \frac{1}{r}
$$
Solving for $r$ yields $(1 + \sqrt{5})/2$. The other root is extraneous.